# How to execute some functions for each task(partition) and some functions for each element in the partition?

Tags: pyspark

**I am new to PySpark programming, so bear with me if my terminologies are incorrect. I have a 5 node cluster with a shared filesystem. The pyspark flow works fine**

I want to run multiple tasks with each task containing 'x' elements. Each task should create one file (as defined in the init function), and write values executed on each element (by push_track_info) to that corresponding file.

I tried it with foreach and foreachpartition, but until now I could only write code that creates one file for one element, whereas my requirement is one file per task, but one operation on each element in the task. How do I do about doing this ?

```
class MyClass:
def __init__(self): 
    self.track = SparkCheck()       
    self.cluster_output_tree ='test.root'
    self.f1 = TFile(self.cluster_output_tree, 'RECREATE')
    self.tree_tracks = TTree('tracks_spark', 'Tree containing Tracks found through clustering')
    self.branch = self.tree_tracks.Branch('Events_Spark', 'SparkCheck', AddressOf(self.track), 32000, 99)

def push_tracks_info(self, i):
    self.check = MyClass()
    self.track.event = 1 +i
    self.track.timestamp = 1000+i
    self.tree_tracks.Fill()
    self.tree_tracks.Write()
    return self.track

sc = SparkContext("spark://ksf141i:7077", "Test App")
sc.addPyFile('myclass.py')
sc.addPyFile('settings.py')
check = MyClass()
rdd5 = sc.parallelize(range(100))
rdd5.foreach(lambda entry: check.push_tracks_info(entry))
```

Comment: Could you please add more context? How did you code the Write function? What do you mean by tasks, are them those 100 you are iterating? Please, check out also this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By tasks, I mean numSlices in parallelize(c, numSlices=None). In my case, it would be sc.parallelize(range(100),10). For each of the 10 Slices, I would like to create a file, so it would be 10 files in total, each file containing 10 entries. Fill(), Write() are from external libraries that I am importing to Python, but it works in stand alone as well in spark modes. Problem is right now, I have 100 files with 1 entry each.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is mapPartitionwithIndex. The index helps with identifying each task and the iterator for the index helps with handling events within the task.